# Unble to click on a link using WATIN

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, watin

```html
<section>
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center ">
        <a id="submitButton" class="btn btn-lg mt40">Reset password</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

```csharp
browser1.Link(Find.ById("submitButton")).KeyPress('\r');  
browser1.Link(Find.ById("submitButton")).Highlight(true); 
browser1.Link(Find.ById("submitButton")).Click();

var linky = browser1.ElementOfType<Link>("submitButton");      

Console.WriteLine(linky.ToString());

linky.MouseEnter();
linky.FireEvent("mouseover");
linky.FireEvent("onclick");
linky.Click();
linky.KeyPress('\r');
```

Please help me in clicking that link using Watin in C#. I have tried various methods, but they are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
browser1.Document.GetElementByID("submitButton").InvokeMember("Click");
```

Comment: Error 1 'WatiN.Core.IE' does not contain a definition for 'Document' and no extension method 'Document' accepting a first argument of type 'WatiN.Core.IE' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
getting an below error